# Why other definitions of convergence fail to be correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definition

The following is an exercise from the book Advanced Calculus:

[image]

Well obviously the **b.** is not correct since for $\epsilon= \frac19$, ${\{a_n}\}={\{\frac1n}\}$ and $N=2$ it fails to be correct. But the **a.** and the **c.** are exactly as same as the accepted definition of convergence which is given in the book, i.e.

> **Definition.** A sequence ${\{a_n}\}$ is said to converge to the number a provided that for every positive number $\epsilon$ there is an index $N$ such that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for all indices $n \ge N$.

In fact, the **a.** and the **c.** are just re-phrasing the above mentioned definition.

Please help!

Comment: $a$ is obviously not true either, since you could just use $a_n=a+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.  And $c$ can be phrased "eventually each $a_n$ equals $a$", which is again, trivially false.

Comment: c. basically states that the sequence is eventually constant

Comment: For (a), it has to be for all $\epsilon > 0$. (c) is stronger than the definition, in the sense that $N$ doesn't depend on $\epsilon$. The order of your quantifiers in a sentence is crucial in math. "For all $\epsilon$, exists $N$" is different from "Exists $N$, for all $\epsilon$". In the previous case, $N$ depends on $\epsilon$. In the latter case, $N$ doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same! For the first, "For some" means "for at least one but not necessarily all". Here, you want to use that if you can't choose an *arbitrary* $ε$, then $1/n$ will converge to more than one number.

For the third, "For all A there exists B" is very different from "there exists B for all A". For every cow there is a glass of milk vs for every glass of milk there is a cow. if $1/n$ satisfied this definition it would be identically zero for $n>N$.

Comment: I got it all! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

No, *a* and *c* are not the same! Those changes you call "rephrasings" totally change the meaning - that's the point to the exercise.

Let $\epsilon=3$. Let $N=1$. Then $|1/n-1| < \epsilon$ for every $n>N$.

So it is true that for *some* $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ so $|1/n-1|<\epsilon$ for every $n>N$. Which is what **a** says - if **a** is the definition of limit we've just proved that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=1.$$

And if **c** were the same as the actual definition that it would *not* be true that $\lim 1/n = 0$. Because **c** does *not* hold here - it is not true that there is an $N$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $|1/n-0|<\epsilon$ for every $n>N$. Given $N$, let $\epsilon=N/3$ and $n=2N$. Then $n>N$ but $|1/n-0|>\epsilon$.

Answer (score -1):

For $a$, the problem is the phrase *for all indicies*. Choose small number $\epsilon$ and go to work. For $c$, the problem is the phrase *There is an index N.* If you fix $N$ in advance and then choose epsilon later, you will run into a problem. So given $N$, how do you choose $\epsilon$ to make your counterexample $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ work?